# Removing Text from Part of String

Tags: javascript, string, function, substring, substr

I am needing to remove text within different strings.

I need a function that will make the following...

```
test: example1
preview: sample2
sneakpeak: model3
view: case4
```

...look like this:

```
example1
sample2
model3
case4
```

I have tried using the `substr` and `substring` functions but was not able to find a solution.

I used `selected.substr(0, selected.indexOf(':'))` but all that returned to me was the text before the colon. `selected` is the variable that contains the string of text.

With the strings being different lengths, it's something that cannot be hardcoded either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. split will return an array. To remove spaces use trim()

```js
var res = "test: example1".split(':')[1].trim();

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Rataiczak24 glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

[**`substring`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) takes two parameters: the start of the cut and the end of the cut (optional).

[**`substr`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) takes two parameters: the start of the cut and the length of the cut (optional).

You should use `substr` with one parameter only, the start of the cut (omitting the second parameter will make `substr` cut from the start index to the end):

```
var result = selected.substr(selected.indexOf(':'));
```

You may want to `trim` the result to remove the spaces around result:

```
var result = selected.substr(selected.indexOf(':')).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getNewStr(str, delimeter = ':') {


  return str.substr( str.indexOf(delimeter) + 1).trim();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex `/[a-z]*:\s/gim`
See the example snippet code below

```js
var string = "test: example1\n\
preview: sample2\n\
sneakpeak: model3\n\
view: case4";

var replace = string.replace(/[a-z]*:\s/gim, "");

console.log(replace);
```

The output will be:

```
example1
sample2
model3
case4
```